# MICE 2l.pan multilevel multiple imputation error: missing values in pred not allowed

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I'm using `MICE` in `R` to perform multiple imputation on multilevel data.

Where only continuous data requires imputation, I have used 2l.lmer with success.
However things go wrong when I try to impute categorical data i.e. level 2 data.

(Level 1:
repeated measurements (within subjects) or subjects (within classes)
Level 2:
time-constant/baseline covariates, between subjects effects, variables on the group level)

I am trying to use `2l.pan` in combination with `2lonly.norm` or `2lonly.mean` however I get an error message "missing values in pred not allowed".

I'm sure it's something simple.

Please see below for a reproducible example.

Many thanks.

````
library("mice")
library("pan")

#Not multilevel to illustrate need

set.seed(100)
patid <- rep(1:3, each = 5)
day <- rep(1:5, times = 3)
crp <- c(68, 78, 93, NA, 143, 5,7,9,13,NA, 97, NA, 56, 52, 34)
sex <- rep(c("M", "F", "M"), each = 5)
sex[3] <- NA
alb <- c(23, NA, 22, 21, 20, 33, 32, 32, NA, 30, 19, 20, NA, 22, 24)

raw_data.df <- data.frame(patid, sex, day, crp, alb)

data_mice.df <- mice(raw_data.df, m = 5, maxit = 5)
complete(data_mice.df)


#pt4's crp not well predicted, and pt1 allocated wrong sex, so try multilevel

##multilevel

pred <- data_mice.df$predictorMatrix

pred[,"patid"] <- -2 #identify class variable
pred[,"day"] <- 0 #don't use time
pred


multilevel_mice <- mice(raw_data.df, method = c("","2lonly.norm","","2l.pan","2l.pan"), predictorMatrix = pred, maxit = 5)```


Error message:
iter imp variable
  1   1  sex  crpError in pan::pan(y1, subj, pred, xcol, zcol, prior, seed = s1, iter = paniter) : 
  missing values in pred not allowed
````

Comment: Any help here? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49119/diagnosing-why-mice-is-crashing-r-when-attempting-to-impute-multilevel-data

Comment: You don't need `mice` to impute the one missing gender of `id==1`. Better example would be to change `sex[patid==1] <- NA`. However this also gives an error (different one).

Comment: This is a bug in `mice`. I'll need to track it down.Thanks for alerting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues at hand:

1. The `2lonly.norm()` method is meant for numeric variables and doesn't really handle factor variables that well. The problem here is that `sex` is imputed `NA`, which causes a problem further down the stream when imputing `crp`, which expects a complete set of predictors.
2. Since we know that `sex` does not change within `patid` a more appropriate method is `2lonly.mean`. However, until now `2lonly.mean` also wasn't suitable for second-level factors.

`mice 3.6.4` at https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice extends `mice.impute.2lonly.mean()` to factors. After installing this version, then you should be able to run

```r
multilevel_mice <- mice(raw_data.df, method = c("","2lonly.mean","","2l.pan","2l.pan"), predictorMatrix = pred, maxit = 5)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Additional note: `2lonly.norm` and `2lonly.pmm` are methods for imputing 2nd-level variables. Thus, you could use them these if ALL `sex` fields for `patid` are missing. Extend your example to 4 persons, with one person missing all sex values.